# How to count length after split in ruby except some values inside the string?

Tags: ruby, split

I want to count the length of items in a string after splitting by a delimiter (,).

```
str = 'a,3,b,c,0'
count = str.split(',').length # => 5

str = '0'
count = str.split(',').length # => 1
```

How to count **except** the value '0'? Output should be 4 instead of 5. Or 0 instead of 1.

Thank you.

**update**

thanks to all replies. I've tried it all and it's all working well!

Comment: Why 0 should be excluded? Is it because of its position in both examples or just you don't need it?

Comment: yes, I just don't need to count 0 in any string. Even if there's 1 or more zeroes inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think in terms of receivers. You send `split` to a string and it returns an array. You then send `length` to that array:

```
str.split(',')
#=> ["a", "3", "b", "c", "0"]

str.split(',').length
#=> 4
```

So in order to exclude `'0'`, you could create an array that doesn't contain the unwanted elements and call `length` on that array: (e.g. via [`difference`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#difference-method))

```
str.split(',').difference(['0'])
#=> ["a", "3", "b", "c"]

str.split(',').difference(['0']).length
#=> 4
```

or you could call [`count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#count-method) and specify to only count elements that are not `'0'`:

```
str.split(',').count { |x| x != "0" }
#=> 4
```

Comment: The good thing about `difference` is that you can pass multiple arguments, otherwise you can use `Array#-`.

Comment: [`grep_v`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) would also be a good option here `str.split(',').grep_v('0').length`

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

```
str = 'a,3,b,c,0' 
count = (str.split(',') - ['0']).length # => 4

str = '0'
count = (str.split(',') - ['0']).length # => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the elements you want to ignore:

```
count = str.split(',').reject {|c| c=='0'}.length
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep your code as it's, but just remove the zero(s) before splitting the string:

```
'a,3,b,c,0'.tr('0', '').split(',').length    # 4
'0'.tr('0', '').split(',').length            # 0
'a,3,10,b,c,0'.tr('0', '').split(',').length # 5
'0,0'.tr('0', '').split(',').length          # 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One can operate on the string directly, avoiding the need for a temporary array, such as the one created by splitting the string on commas.

```
def countem(str)
  str.gsub(/(?<![^,])(?=0*[1-9])/).count
end

puts countem "1,2,0,3,0,45"
  #=> 4
puts countem "00,1,2,000,45,0"
  #=> 3
```

The steps are as follows.

```
str = "00,1,2,000,45,0"

r = /(?<![^,])(?=0*[1-9])/
```

The regex engine maintains a pointer that is the *current location* in the string. That location is at the beginning or end of the string or between two consecutive characters.

`(?<![^,])` is a *negative lookbedhind* that asserts that the current location is not preceded by a character other than a comma; that is, the current location is at the beginning of the string or the preceding character is a comma.

`(?=0*[1-9])/`  is a *positive lookahead* that asserts that the current location is followed by zero or more zeroes, followed by a digit other than zero. That is, it asserts that current location is followed by a sequence of digits that are not all zeroes.

The regex matches the string held by `str` in three locations: between `,` and `1`, between `,` and `2` and between `,` and `45`. Each match is an empty string.

```
enum = str.gsub(r) #=> #<Enumerator:0x00562f74d24a98>
```

As seen at the doc for [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), `gsub` returns an enumerator that generates matches of its argument, here a regular expression, when, as here, no block is provided. In this case the method loses its meaning as replacing strings with other strings.

We can see the elements that will be generated by `enum` by converting it to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["", "", ""]
```

Lastly,

```
enum.count
  #=> 3
```